# statistical find -exec

Tags: find, exec

I want to run a command over some percentage of the files that find finds.  I'll use **puts** here instead of the real code.

```
find . -type f -exec ruby -e "puts '{}' if (rand > 0.2)" \;
```

I have a lot of files.  Is there a way to do this without calling rand or even using Ruby?

I thought about using **mod X** on the filesize, since the files are more or less random length but I can't figure out a way to tell find to use that in an expression.

Answer (score 3):

This prints 50% of the files:

```
   find . -exec bash -c "echo -n \$RANDOM | tail -c 1 | grep -q [0-4]" \; -print
```

To execute something, this should work:

```
   find . -exec bash -c "echo -n \$RANDOM | tail -c 1 | grep -q [0-4]" \; -exec my_command \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a better way:

```
find . -type f | ruby -n -e 'puts $_.chop if (rand > 0.5)'
```

If you have a *lot* of files, execing a bash shell for each one can chew up resources.  The above line starts one long running ruby process that simply processes the input from find.  It's much faster.